# all transcational email are going to junk in Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9

All transcational email from the Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 is going to junk in gmail

Answer (score 0):

You can try below links :

http://inchoo.net/magento/fight-spam-emails/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564033/magento-email-goes-to-spam-or-junk-mail

https://blog.amasty.com/5-steps-for-no-spam-e-mails-in-magento/

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-avoid-spam-emails-magento/

Keep this as **last** option. If you are sending emails through server, than try sending emails through 3rd party [SMTP extension](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension)

Here is a piece of code from that extension :

```
class Aschroder_SMTPPro_Smtp_LogController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    protected function _initAction() {
        // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('system/tools')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('System'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('System'))
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Tools'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Tools'))
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Email Log'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Email Log'));
        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {

          $this->_initAction()
            ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smtppro/log'))
            ->renderLayout();

    }   

    public function viewAction() {

          $this->_initAction()
            ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smtppro/log_view'))
            ->renderLayout();


    }

    /**
     * Check is allowed access to action
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed() {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/system/tools/smtppro');
    }

}
```

I hope you will get better solution than this....